# Big QUERY conditional statement for a field arrays

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In big query, I am trying to show the array only if the array is not empty and else we return 0. The field "url" is an array with a type of string, however I am having difficulty implementing the logic. Side note I will not be able to use a where filter to filter the data but rather keep the original data and just perform a check on the field and have a placeholder of 0 is it's empty.

```
WITH temp_ as(
SELECT
    ASE_IDD,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
      DESCRIPTION,
      r"regex_placeholder") as url
     
  FROM
    table)
   
  SELECT ASE_IDD, IF ( (url is not NULL), url, 0) from temp_
```

here is my error:

```
1::SQL_ANALYSIS_ERROR: No matching signature for function IF for argument types: BOOL, ARRAY<STRING>, INT64. Supported signature: IF(BOOL, ANY, ANY) (Line: 13, Column: 20)
```

Any help would be much appreciated !!

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear . . . `0` is not an array of strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big Query SQL check if an array is null otherwise return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68355449/big-query-sql-check-if-an-array-is-null-otherwise-return-0)

Comment: isn't it going to generate same exact error?!